# Eigen3 CMake error on Jenkins builds

Tags: ros, jenkins, eigen3, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have built a package, [freefloating_gazebo](https://github.com/freefloating-gazebo/freefloating_gazebo),  that is now being compiled regularly on Jenkins.
I have a constant error in CMake :

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindEigen3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" with any
  of the following names:

    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

So I understand that Eigen3 is not installed in the Jenkins machine.
Maybe the compilation is not correctly configured, but I cannot find where I should do any changes.

Can I write in my package that I have a dependency on Eigen3, so that it can be installed automatically, or should I do it manually?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224104/eigen3-cmake-error-on-jenkins-builds/) by [Olivier Kermorgant](https://answers.ros.org/users/11856/olivier-kermorgant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 280 on 2016-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> So I understand that Eigen3 is not installed in the Jenkins machine. Maybe the compilation is not correctly configured, but I cannot find where I should do any changes.

Looking at your [package.xml](https://github.com/freefloating-gazebo/freefloating_gazebo/blob/f3b1da8522e87e08b8b7bccbd000553672bf6511/package.xml) you don't express a (build) dependency on Eigen anywhere. The buildfarm only installs the minimum set of packages needed to build things. So you need to tell it to make sure Eigen(3) is also in that set.

See [catkin 0.6.16 documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 1 (legacy) » C++ system library dependencies](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/system_library_dependencies.html) for information on how to do that (seeing as you're still using package format 1, the link takes you to that version of the documentation. For package format version 2, see [catkin 0.6.16 documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 2 (recommended) » C++ system library dependencies](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/system_library_dependencies.html)).

See also [Eigen CMake Module in cmake_modules](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Migration#Eigen_CMake_Module_in_cmake_modules) about Eigen(3) in Jade and newer in the Jade migration guide.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Olivier Kermorgant](https://answers.ros.org/users/11856/olivier-kermorgant/) on 2016-01-14**:
Great, thanks. That's exactly what I missed, how to express a build dependency on an external lib.

I'll give it a try.

**Comment by [Olivier Kermorgant](https://answers.ros.org/users/11856/olivier-kermorgant/) on 2016-01-18**:
Working fine with eigen, it was as simple as that.